# Producer / Consumers problem question

Tags: multithreading, unix, fork, semaphore, shared-memory

I am going to implement a program where one parent process reads a text file and feeds the data he's reading into a shared memory buffer that's going to be read by some children processes. All this work will be mediated by semaphores. Let's assume the parent is going to read one character at a time from the file and the shared memory buffer contains 5 slots.

At first, I thought of only having 2 semaphores:

`writeSemaphore`, initialized to 5, is the semaphore that tells whether the writer is allowed to write to the buffer. when it finally goes down to 0, the parent process will be blocked until one of the children unlocks it (after having read some block).

`readSemaphore`, initialized to 0, is the semaphore that tells whether any of the readers is allowed to read from the buffer.

But now that I think of it, this wouldn't prevent me from having 2 consumers accessing the the shared memory at the same time. I must prevent it. So I introduced a third semaphore:

`allowedToRead` that is either 1 or 0, that allows or blocks access to the children processes.

Here is pseudo code for both children and parent:

Child:

```
while (something) {
    wait(readSemaphore)
    wait(allowedToRead)
    <<read from shared memory>>
    post(allowedToRead)
    post(writeSemaphore)
}
```

Parent:

```
while (something) {
    wait(writeSemaphore)
    <<writes to shared memory>>
    post(allowedToRead)
}
```

Is my reasoning correct?

Thanks

Comment: You could find Boost.Interprocess useful to save you some of the heavy lifting in handling shared memory.  There are direct process-to-process streaming constructs described here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/interprocess/streams.html

Comment: This is for school, so no boost for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Khachik is half right. He's may be all right, but his description isn't as clear as it could be.

Firstly, where you have the parent posting `allowedToRead` you probably mean for it to post `readSemaphore`.

Secondly your code allows the parent to write at the same time as a child is reading. You say you have 5 slots. If the parent writes to a different slot than the child is reading then this is ok I suppose, but how does the child determine where to read? Is it using the same variables as the parent is using to determine where to write? You probably need some extra protection there. After all I assume the different children are all reading different slots, so if you need to prevent them treading one ach other's toes you'll need to do the same for the parent too.

Thirdly, I'd have used a mutex instead of a semaphore for `allowedToRead`.

Fourthly, what determines which child reads which data or is it meant to be first come first served like pigs at a slop bucket?

If the shared memory has 5 independant slots, then I'd be inclined to add a "next read" and "next write" variable. Protect those two variables with a mutex in both producer and consumers, and then use the semaphores just to block/trigger reading and writing as you are already doing. If it weren't a school exercise, you could do better using a single condition variable attached to the mutex I mentioned. When it gets signalled the parent checks if he can write and the children check if they can read. When either a read or a write occurs, signal the condition variable globally to wake everybody up to check their conditions. This has the advantage that if you have independant buffer slots then you can safely and happily have multiple consumers consuming at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

No.

1. the writer should release `readSemaphore` when it write one unit of information;
2. the writer should acquire `allowedToRead` lock (0,1 semaphore is a lock/mutex) before writing to shared memory to prevent race conditions.

To simplify: consider two functions `read_shared_memory`, `write_shared_memory`, which are to read and write from/to the shared memory respectively and both acquiring/releasing the same lock before reading/writing.

The producer acquires write semaphore, calls the write function, releases the read semaphore.
The consumer acquire read semaphore, calls the read function, releases the the write semaphore.

Sure this can be implemented without read/write functions, they are just to simplify using atomic access to the shared memory. A critical section can be implemented inside produce/consume loops without additional functions.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem#Using_semaphores) describes it in more scientific way :)

Comment: I still don't understand what is the problem with my implementation. What race condition could I get? When Producer is writing, the consumrs are waiting. When the consumers are reading, only one of them can be at a time.

Comment: it only complains about race conditions with several producers -- i only have 1.